# How to make area height fog in Unity, ex Forest area has fog, road area doesn't

Tags: unity-game-engine

Unity Render Settings fog is depend on Distance, I want create Environment Height Area fog, for example, the map forest area has fog effect, and the map road area doesn't has fog. How to create the fog?

Comment: Hi see [this](https://answers.unity.com/questions/310238/adding-fog.html) for fog, also your question is does not show any research work. Or tell where are you facing problem ?

Comment: Unity Render Settings fog is depend on Distance, I want create Environment Height Area fog, for example, the map forest area has fog effect, and the map road area doesn't has fog. How to create the fog?

Comment: Please update that this too properly in the question.